# Routing in ASP.NET Webforms .NET 4.0 - GetVirtualPath returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, webforms, url-routing

I have the following code in a static class named RouteConfig, called by App_Start:

```
// Create routes with default values for parameters

routes.MapPageRoute(
"SearchResultsRoute",
"SearchResults/{delegatesurname}/{starsid}/{dealercode}/{leadassessorid}/{locationid} /{datefrom}/{dateto}/{statusid}",
"~/SearchResults.aspx",
false,
new RouteValueDictionary
{
    {"delegatesurname", string.Empty},
    {"starsid", string.Empty},
    {"dealercode", string.Empty},
    {"leadassessorid", 0},
    {"locationid", 0},
    {"datefrom", string.Empty},
    {"dateto", string.Empty},
    {"statusid", 0}
}
);

// EnableFriendlyUrls() is removed, as that was blocking the routing for some reason.
```

I also have a class called "Navigator" that contains a method to build a URL:

```
protected string GetUrlFromRouteAndParams(string routeName, IDictionary<string,object> parameters)
{
    var routeDict = new RouteValueDictionary(parameters);
    var q = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, routeName, routeDict);
    return ""; // ignore this line its not pertinent to question
}
```

Now when I call GetUrlFromRouteAndParams above, like so:

```
    var pageParams = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"delegatesurname", _view.DelegateSurname}                
        {"starsid", _view.STARSID},
        {"dealercode", _view.DealerCode},
        {"leadassessorid", _view.LeadAssessorID},
        {"locationid", _view.LocationID},
        {"datefrom", string.Empty },
        {"dateto", string.Empty},
        {"statusid", 0} 
    };

    var url = navigator.GetUrlFromRouteAndParams("SearchResultsRoute", pageParams);
```

The GetVirtualPath call in GetUrlFromRouteAndParams above returns null.

Why is this? And how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you getting any value in q?

Comment: q is null, suggesting that the route cannot be found, but I have tested it via entering the URL searchresults/Scott/ into the browser and it works just fine.

Comment: I also removed EnableFriendlyUrls() as that interfered with the routing

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: Hi Sid, yes I did, I get an exception thrown because GetVirtualPath returns null, and am accessing VirtualPath property on null object.

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: NullReferenceException

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
//var routeDict = new RouteValueDictionary(parameters);
var q = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, routeName, null).VirtualPath;
return q.ToString();
```